# How can I assign a value of nested response json object to a variable by using Cypress & JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, cypress

How can I assign a value of nested response json object to a variable? For Example; I saw this answer for similar question under another stackoverflow question but I can't see a solution in this answer in order to set 'Dummy 3' value to a variable like below.

```
const myVariable = cy.get('@sample')
    .its('body')
    .its('sample')
    .its('1')
    .its('names')
    .its(0).as('string')
```

Response JSON:

```
{
  "sample": [
    { "names": ["Dummy 1", " Dummy 2"] },
    { "names": ["Dummy 3", " Dummy 4"] },
    { "names": ["Dummy 5", " Dummy 6"] }
  ]
}
```

The last object in the array should be accessed as:

```
// to check a child's length
  cy.get('@sample')
    .its('body') // 'responseBody' in case of latest cypress version
    .its('sample')
    .its('2')
    .its('names')
    .its('length')
    .should('eq', 2);

// To check content
  cy.get('@sample')
    .its('body') // 'responseBody' in case of latest cypress version
    .its('sample')
    .its('2')
    .its('names')
    .its(1)
    .should('include', '6');
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you've yielded the body, you can just use standard JS functions to find your specific values.

```js
cy.get('@sample')
  .its('body')
  .then((body) => {
    return body.sample[2].names // return the array to the Cypress chain
  })
  .should('have.length', 2)
  .its(1)
  .should('contain', '6');
```

You could also alias the value to be used in the same test, or store it as a `Cypress.env()` variable.

```js
// alias
cy.get('@sample')
  .its('body')
  .then((body) => {
    return body.sample[2].names 
  }).as('someValue');

// Cypress.env
cy.get('@sample')
  .its('body')
  .then((body) => {
    Cypress.env('someValue', body.sample[2].names);
  })
```